# Abandonar iteracion de foreach sin salir del bucle

Tags: c#, foreach

En un `foreach`, en la que en cada iteración se ejecutan varias instrucciones, ¿Puedo abandonar una iteración sin salir del `foreach`?
Es decir que la iteración en curso no tenga que ejecutar todas las instrucciones si no cumple cierta condición, pero seguir con la siguiente iteración.
Algo así como break; pero que me mantenga dentro del `foreach`.

gracias.

Comment: Pero un return me hará salir del foreach no?

Comment: ¿Para eso no son las funciones? Si cumple una condición, ejecuta la función. La función al terminar regresará a donde fue llamada, así sea dentro de un ciclo.

Comment: No hay que abandonar el `foreach` ni suspender la iteración, solo tienes que colocar esas instrucciones que no tengan que ejecutarse, si no se cumple cierta condición, dentro de un bloque condicional, un `if` por ejemplo, todo dentro del bloque `foreach`.

Comment: @EduardoReyes , si eso está claro, solo era por practicidad, ya que es una función de 100 líneas y el condicional está al principio y era por no tener un `else` que contenga 90 líneas. Algo debo hacer mal con el `return`, ya que a mi me abandona iteración y bucle.

Comment: Tendrás que hacer uso de condicionales if, y si tienes tantas líneas de código crea un método aparte para cada bloque de instrucciones de forma que tendrás if (...) LlamoAlMetodo1(); else if (...) LlamoAlMetodo2(); else OtraCosa(); así tu código será más legible y entendible, se ejecuta sólo el grupo de instrucciones si la condición es verdadera solo que las tienes ubicadas en un método.

Comment: Tu bucle está dentro de una función; `return` abandona la función, por tanto abandonara todo lo que esté dentro de ella, incluido el bucle y todas las instrucciones posteriores al `return`. Un bucle con 100 lineas dentro es algo serio, pero si hay varias que no deben ejecutarse si no se cumple cierta condición, pues no hay forma mas practica que colocar un bloque condicional, para eso son los bloques condicionales.

Comment: O simplemente utiliza [`continue;`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) en vez de `break;`, que precisamente permite saltarse la iteración actual.

Comment: @Benito-B Ves, eso si hace exactamente lo que pedía.

Comment: Como dice @Benito-B, la solución es `continue`, mira la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue)

Answer (score -1):

Para saltar la iteración, pero no salir del bucle debes usar la palabra reservada `continue`, si usas el `break` saldrás completamente del bucle.

Aquí esta un ejemplo.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if(i == 3) continue;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Igual te dejo el link de la documentación.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue

Comment: Esto es un comentario como mucho, no una respuesta. Te recomiendo que si vas a responder, añadas alguna explicación así como fuentes (enlaces a la documentación por ejemplo) y/o ejemplos.